# Unable to locate package nss-devel - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, nss

What is the debian equivalent of nss-devel package?

**apt-get install nss-devel** is not working.

Comment: Are you looking for [`libnss3-dev'`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnss3-dev)?

Answer (score 5):

There's no such package in Ubuntu repo. The name is for Red Hat repo, or any other RPM-based Linux.

The correct package in Ubuntu is `libnss3-dev`. Although you may find some other packages, like `libnss3` and `libnss3-1g`. I suggest to install them all.

Anyway, run `sudo apt-get upgrade libnss3*` returns you a complete list. For my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libnss-cache' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-mysql-bg' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss3-tools' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss3-nssdb' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-securepass' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-docker' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-db' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-mysql' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-lwres' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-mymachines' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss3-1d' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-ldapd' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-mdns' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-myhostname' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-winbind' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-wrapper' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-rainbow2' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-sss' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-gw-name' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss3-1d-dbg' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-resolve' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss3' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-pgsql1' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-pgsql2' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-ldap' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-extrausers' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss3-dbg' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss3-dev' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss-rsbac2' for glob '*libnss*'
Note, selecting 'libnss3-dbg' instead of 'libnss3-1d-dbg'
Note, selecting 'libnss-pgsql2' instead of 'libnss-pgsql1'
libnss-mdns is already the newest version (0.10-7).
libnss-mdns set to manually installed.
libnss3 is already the newest version (2:3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libnss3 set to manually installed.
libnss3-1d is already the newest version (2:3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libnss3-dbg is already the newest version (2:3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libnss3-dev is already the newest version (2:3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libnss3-nssdb is already the newest version (2:3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libnss3-nssdb set to manually installed.
libnss3-tools is already the newest version (2:3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libnss3-tools set to manually installed.
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss-ldapd : Conflicts: libnss-ldap
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try

```
 apt-get update
```

and

```
 apt-cache search nss
```

Comment: Tried apt-get update got the same error:"E: Unable to locate package nss-devel"

Comment: @KurinchiMalar - what is the result after "apt-cache search" ?

Comment: It is a huge list of "libnss". I'm not able to locate a specific package.